# Regex to match a price string

Tags: php, regex, string

I am new in PHP. I was trying to check if one of the form inputs (contained in `$price` for this example) is a decimal as follows:

```
if(!preg_match("\\d+(.\\d{1,2})?", $price))
    //do something
```

In Java, it would have been

```
price.matches("\\d+(.\\d{1,2})?")
```

But the same regex is not working in PHP. Does `preg_match` match substrings as well?

I expect the following inputs to be true:

```
300
300.5
300.56
```

All other formats should be false. I cannot figure out how to do that in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's do this right**:

```
is_string($price) and trim($price); // Might be worth doing first
if(preg_match('~^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$~', $price)) {
   $price = floatval($price); // Kewl, keep going
}else{
   // Unkewl, fail
}
```

1. **Wrap RegExp in ~ character**. Any non-reserved character works as a wrapper and / is terrible when dealing with URLs or HTML as you need to escape it too. It's a nightmare.
2. Force the string to **exact match** by **enclosing in ^ and $** and not a **contain** match like all these variants here.
3. **Wrap string in single quotes** if you don't have **PHP "{$variables}"** that need to be expanded in them.
4. **Escape \ even in single quoted** string like this \d or \.!
5. **Don't capture the block**, it does not matter anyway but is a performance thing.

:) Rant done!

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand how that could possibly have worked in Java. The first number only matches a single digit. Your examples match several digits.

Try this regex instead:

```
/\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?/
```

Notice how I've put the regex inside a "wrapper" (the `/`) and notice how I removed your escaping of `\` in front of the number matches. Also I replaced the capture group around your decimals with a non-capture group, because in your context it did not look like you would need it.

PHP code:

```
if (!preg_match("/\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?/",$price)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake :) it would be \\d+ in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I would say

```
\d(\.\d{1,2})?
```

As far as I rememer a dot needs to be escaped as well

Comment: First \d needs a \d+ too. And consider double escaping.

Answer (score 1):

```
(!preg_match("/\d(\.\d{1,2})?/",$price))
```

Remember the starting and ending /'s